# VS Code Python Testing Extension Not Showing Results on the UI (Neither Green Tick nor Red Cross)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I'm using the VS Code Testing Extension to test Pytest and I'm seeing this behavior:

[Gif: VS Code Python Testing Debugger Not Showing Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMrVK.gif)

Note: This test works because running `python3 -m pytest` in the terminal shows me the expected result.

1. The first part of a gif shows that when I use the testing extension to run a different test, it shows that it runs successfully and there's a green tick that appears (Expected behaviour). This test is not a class but rather a `.py` file with multiple functions defined in it. Example:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def something():
    return "A"

def test_1(something):
    assert something == "A"

def test_1(something):
    assert something == "B"
```

2. The second part of the gif shows me running another test but this time the extension just goes into loading and then shows no result and I do not know why this is happening.

---

For the second case, the way I've written my test is as follows:

1. I have a file called `base_test_class.py` which is my Base `pytest` class containing all the common tests. The test file(s) will inherit this class and run the tests defined within it. It is structured as follows:

```
import pytest

class BaseFileTestCases:
    @pytest.fixture()
    def test_data(self, check):
        // Performs some functions

    @pytest.fixture()
    def test_values(self, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8):
        return {
            "var1": None,
            "var2": None,
            "var3": None,
            "var4": None,
            "var5": None,
            "var6": None,
            "var7": None,
            "var8": None
        }

    def test_scan(self, check, test_data, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8):
        A = test_data[var1]
        result = check.function(A, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7)
        assert result == var8
```

2. The test file that inherits the above class (and the one that I ran in the second part of the gif) is structured as follows in `test_my_files.py`:

```
// other imports
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8"),
    [
        ("file1.yaml", None, None, "1.27", None, None, None, True), # Test1 should be True
        ("file2.yaml", None, None, None, None, None, None, True), # Test2 should be False
    ]
)

class TestMyFile(BaseFileTestCases):
    @pytest.fixture()
    def check(self):
        return FuncFromAClass()

    @pytest.fixture()
    def test_values(self, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8):
        return {
            "var1": var1,
            "var2": var2,
            "var3": var3,
            "var4": var4,
            "var5": var5,
            "var6": var6,
            "var7": var7,
            "var8": var8,
        }
```

Again, when I run the tests from the terminal using `python3 -m pytest`, everything works fine and i get the expected results.

I just want to know how I can get the VS Code Python Testing Extension to also show me the result (✅ or ❌) when I run it via the UI. I should add that the debugging function in that works.

Would be very grateful if someone can help me out.

Expected: VS Code Testing UI to show ✅ when the test passed or ❌ when the test failed.

Actual: The test just 'runs' and then shows no result.

Comment: Have you followed the steps as [the document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_run-tests) about testing? It should display whether the testing was successful or failed.

Comment: I tried testing and [it did display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jWUq.png) correctly.

Comment: Oh... I'm confused why it didn't for me. I'll try following the doc again and give it another shot and update here.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT so i found the first issue: I was using another [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter) to run the test and although that worked fine for every other test it was failing in the above scenario i mentioned.

I tried using Python's inbuilt testing framework but it is just giving me ModuleImportError even though i'm in the same `cwd` that is working when used with the above extension. Any ideas? I will be very appreciative, thank you!

Comment: You can search **Execute In File Dir** in settings and check it. Or use debug and add `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` to your `launch.json`